# excel blank cells, countifs & dates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm currently working through a problem that i'm struggling to solve on my own.
I'm asking excel to run a countifs formula with a number of parameters. One of which is if cells within a range have a date less than a declared date parameter, simple enough. However I also want the formula to run if the given date cells are blank. For some reason a blank cell registers as being higher than the given date parameter.

so far i have this
=COUNTIFS(P54:P73,"*",$C54:$C73,">=7/3/22",$C54:$C73,"<=5/6/22",$K54:$K73,"<=06/06/2022")

[image]

However as mentioned rows within this range that fill the other parameters but have a blank in the K column wont be counted.

Please help

Comment: A data sample, entered as **text** which can be copy/pasted, along with the desired output from that same data, would be useful in clarifying your question. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Picture of dataset should now be available

Comment: I'll check back later after you have added the data as text and an example of your desired output.

Comment: The date added column, is that text or date value?

Comment: P.b that column is a date value